# Windows crash dump analysis

Tags: windbg, crash-dumps, debugdiag

I am using the DebugDiag to analyze a crash dump on windows.

This is the report summary description:

**In XXXX.dmp the assembly instruction at msvcr120!abort+4a in C:\Windows\System32\msvcr120.dll from Microsoft Corporation has caused an unknown exception (0x40000015) on thread 26**

And the call stack is:

```
ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+a 
KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+e8 
kernel32!WaitForMultipleObjectsExImplementation+b3 
kernel32!WerpReportFaultInternal+215 
kernel32!WerpReportFault+77 
kernel32!BasepReportFault+1f 
kernel32!UnhandledExceptionFilter+1fc 
msvcr120!_call_reportfault+b6 
msvcr120!abort+4a 
msvcr120!terminate+1e 
msvcp120!_Call_func$catch$0+13 
msvcr120!_CallSettingFrame+20 
msvcr120!__CxxCallCatchBlock+f5 
ntdll!RcConsolidateFrames+3 
msvcp120!_Call_func+14 
msvcr120!_callthreadstartex+17 
msvcr120!_threadstartex+102 
kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+d 
ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+1d
```

Guys, what can I make of this crash dump?

Cheers,

Doron

Comment: `abort` is an effect, not the cause. The cause happened earlier somewhere between `msvcp120!_Call_func+14` and `msvcr120!__CxxCallCatchBlock+f5`. I woud try to get a dump on the first chance exception(s) using procdump from sysinternals and analyze those.

Comment: `dps poi($teb+8) poi($teb+4)` may help you determine what was being called a the time of the exception. Make sure the current thread is the one that caused the exception before running that command.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a C++ try catch statement which more or less adds the exception handling Code msvcr120!__CxxCallCatchBlock+f5 shows that.

kernel32!UnhandledExceptionFilter+1fc 
msvcr120!_call_reportfault+b6

The exception is then probably thrown and is not handled at your code. You may want to inspect the exception deeper in windbg with the source of the application. If this is a managed application then you may want to use SOS extension.

Comment: This probably would have been better as a comment. Also, with the CRT on the stack with no CLR, this is native code.